# Conditional Statement inside Component Tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While there are definitely many ways to achieve the result, I was thinking if we could use conditional statement inside a component tag?

For example, Consider this part of the code in return of stateful component

```
<FlatList
         { this.state.searchCoin ? data = displaySearchCrypto :  data=this.props.cryptoLoaded }
           renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <CoinCard
            key={item["short"]}
            coinShortName = {item["short"]}
            coinName = {item["long"]}
            coinPrice = {item["price"].toFixed(2)}
            marketCap = {(item["mktcap"]/1000000000).toFixed(4)}
            percentChange = {item["perc"].toFixed(2)}
            vwapData={item["vwapData"].toFixed(2)}
            coinImage={"https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + item["long"] + ".png"}
            />
```

Here it is throwing error here

```
   { this.state.searchCoin ? data = displaySearchCrypto :  data=this.props.cryptoLoaded }
```

[Question:] What Can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why would anybody think about doing it like that? The thing you are trying to do, is in that form a syntax error, for the rest, I believe that full code is just to hard to read to be useful

Comment: @Icepickle What do you mean? I think you misinterpreted OPs question. He wants to know how to use a `ternary` inside jsx code.

Comment: @trixn no, he seems to hope to use the ternary inside the attributes or props of his component, a syntax error should given him enough info already

Comment: @Icepickle Why so negative? Just look at the accepted answer. It is totally possible to use a ternary inside props. OP just didn't know how the correct syntax looks like. If you are not willing to come up with an answer just move on. There is no reason to leave rude comments on a valid question.

Comment: @trixn I personally don't see anything negative, this is just feedback about the readability of the code, and a hint that syntax error provide a solution as well. As for the accepted answer, I had also upvoted it, but I really don't see any reason why criticizing code in regard of readability should be viewed as negative? Also, the answer was already given by the time I added my comment, so why would I want to duplicate a response?

Comment: @Icepickle Okay then call it impolite. OP is obviously a beginner and maybe self taught and doesn't know what you know. Starting out with: "Why would anybody think about doing it like that?" is not helpful and if you already saw there is a satisfying answer then just move on. No need for this kind of comments. OP knew his code was wrong. You didn't tell him something new. Also see the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the ternary *inside* the prop definition:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.searchCoin ? displaySearchCrypto : this.props.cryptoLoaded}
/>
```